# Find Number of Palindrome Strings in Array Program Errors

Tags: c++, palindrome

I am writing code that finds the number of palindrome strings in a given array of strings. I think I have the right idea, but I am getting weird errors when I run it. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
int countPalindromes(string s) {
    int size = s.size();
    int counter = 0;
    string forwardSum = "";
    string backwardSum = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = i; j < size; i++){
           forwardSum.push_back(s[j]);
           backwardSum.push_back(s[(n - 1)-j]);  

            if(forwardSum == backwardSum){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
     return counter;
 }
```

Comment: Can you paste the errors?

Comment: erminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Reading symbols from Solution...done.
[New LWP 3678303]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./Solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
To enable execution of this file add
 add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".

Comment: To completely disable this security protection add
 set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
 info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"

Comment: Compiler: Abort Called

Answer (score 2):

```
string forwardSum[] = {};
```

This is an array of zero size (which I don't believe is legal but we'll let that pass)

```
forwardSum[i] = forwardSum[i] + s[j];
```

This is an attempt to access the `ith` element of an array which has zero size.

That's bad.

I'm not really following your code (it's late at night), but I think you probably want `forwardSum` and `backwardSum` to be strings not arrays of strings. And you probably want to use `push_back` to add characters from `s` to those strings. I.e.

```
string forwardSum;
...
forwardSum.push_back(s[j]); // add s[j] to forwardSum
```

But if you really do want `forwardSum` to be an array, then the sensible thing to do would be to use a vector instead.

```
vector<string> forwardSum(size); // a vector of strings with the given size
```

Now that should at least not crash with the rest of your code.

Comment: I updated the code above. I'm not getting all of those errors now, but my code is timing out as shown below:

Comment: Compiler: Terminated due to timeout

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this or does my code still has flaws. More help would be appreciated. Thank you.